# Disk utility, shrink 1 partition, expand the other

Tags: mac, disk-utility, partition

I have two partitions on my external HDD, I shrinked 1 partition (Macintosh Lion) in order to expand the other (Macintosh HD), but I can't drag the lower right corner to expand of the 'Macintosh HD' partition, I can only do it with the 'Macintosh Lion' one, ideas?

[image]

Comment: Same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Added the picture for you. May not show up for awhile; I don't have edit privileges yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Disk Utility can’t edit space in the “middle” of the disk, only space on the “ends”.

There is an app called [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) that sounds like it does what you need. From the website:

> iPartition makes it easy to create, destroy, resize or format partitions on your hard disks, whether internal, external, fixed or removable.

Two caveats: first, I’ve never used iPartition myself, so I can’t comment on its reliability. I’ve used their other product (iDefrag), which was very stable and I’d recommend, but not iPartition. Also, according to [archived blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20120706173355/http://www.coriolis-systems.com/blog/2011/07/lion-compatibility.php), iPartition doesn’t work with Lion FileVault partitions. Don’t know if that affects you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are restricted in that sense, you can only modify the partition space "at the end" of the disk, as you have discovered.